# ::after on :hover does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I have found some strange behaviour in Internet Explorer (IE10 and also when emulating all versions that support `::after`). When applying the pseudo-element to a hover state of an element (`.element:hover::after`) it does not work in IE, but it does in all other major browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/9jpeZ/1/

```
#d1::after { /* Works in IE */
  content: "no hover needed";
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
}

#d2:hover::after { /* Does not work in IE */
  content: "Y U NO WORK IN IE";
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
}
```

Is there a CSS fix available for this? (No JS/jQuery.)

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class (one colon). `::after` is not a pseudo-class, but a pseudo-element (two colons). These are two different things. That said, if `::after` is working but `:hover::after` isn't, then something else is wrong, because your fiddle works perfectly in IE9... as it should.

Comment: @BoltClock Ow, stupid mistake! And, you mean to tell me  that the hover state (and showing of the `after` element) works for you? Here (Windows 8, 64 bit) it does not for IE10, 9 or 8.

Comment: Strange... it works for me on IE9 on Windows 7.

Comment: And you are **sure** that the hover state works? I think I'll contact MS then.

Comment: Its not working for me in IE10 on Win8

Comment: Similar CSS is, however working on my website. I'm trying to work out the differences.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in IE10 (even when it emulates other versions).

I have, though, found a workaround. If you add an empty CSS rule for `#d2:hover`, it will then listen to `#d2:hover::after` as shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W45kU/).

Comment: Nice find! Damn IE. I suppose I'll need to report this anyway.

Comment: Nice find. This (combined with the workaround) is eerily similar to Chrome's issue with attribute selectors, except that affects Chrome on every platform. No idea if it's been fixed yet.

Comment: @BoltClock - alas because IE10 is WIn8 only, we don't know if its platform independent or not.

Comment: @BramVanroy - I only found it because I knew it worked on my website and step by step made your CSS identical to mine! Yes, it does need reporting really - I agree.

Comment: @jaypeagi Internet Explorer 10 is **not** just for Windows 8. It is currently available on Windows 7 too.

Comment: @JonathanSampson it seems the preview is available on Win 7 but not the final release?

Comment: @jaypeagi Correct, but it's sufficient to test against for now regarding issues like this. Microsoft is currently accepting bug reports for Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had an instance where this wasn't working in IE as well, 
When I switched the order of ":hover" and ":after" in my style sheet from

```
    .myclassname::after:hover
```

to

```
    .myclassname:hover::after
```

I was able to get the desired result, all the way back to IE9 (didn't test anything lower)