# The combination of a transition and a pseudo element does not work in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to show/hide a line under an element using a `transition: border-bottom .5s` in combination of a `::first-letter` pseudo element. The pseudo element is just to make the first character `bold`. It works well in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but IE does nothing at all.

One work around would be to use a simple html `<b></b>` instead of css solution `::first-letter {font-weight: bold;}`. However, that's not what I want.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cffzdd2r/).

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: @Huangism I can reproduce the issue in IE11.

Comment: Seems that IE isn't doing so well in the pseudo-element departement. (Don't get me wrong, they've done some great work compared to, say, IE7, but there's a lot more to do.) I've had [some similar problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321878/after-on-hover-does-not-work-in-ie) with IE.

Comment: @BramVanroy Very true. I hope that Spartan is better :) Apparently they have gutted most of the existing rendering engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other work-around that I can think of would be to use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element for the `border-bottom`. In doing so, it seems to work in IE.

In the example below, the `:after` pseudo element is absolutely positioned *relative* to the top of the parent.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gn2s4wLr/)

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom .5s;
}
a:hover:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}
a:first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a>my test link</a>
```

Comment: Now it also works well in IE. Just a bit more complex :(