# Tooltip doesn't work on IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, tooltip, internet-explorer-10

I am wondering why my tool tip doesn't work on IE 10. I checked the attributes and I don't find any are not supported by IE 10. It works fine on IE 11 and Chrome. Any ideas? Thank you very much!!

```css
.badge:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.badge::before {
  content: attr(data-name);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="badge apple" data-name="Apple">A</div>
```

Comment: I added a simplified version of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My smart colleague found this -- It's IE 10 bug. The solution is here -- [::after on :hover does not work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321878/after-on-hover-does-not-work-in-ie)

But I choose not to add empty `#ID:hover` block, because it will be ignored by minifier

```
    /**
     * Fix for IE10 bug. This block could be empty, but the minifier would remove it.
     */
    #id:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```